# getting a view WIDTH with match_parent property?

Tags: android, view, width

I have an `imageView` with `layout_width="match_parent"`.

On my adapter's `getView()`, I'd like to get the actual width of this `imageView` but don't know how.

I tried using `imageView.getWidth()`, but this returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is not attached to its parent group in `getView()`, so it hasn't been measured, hence the zero width.  The only way I can think of is to do a `parent.getWidth()` which returns the width of the ViewGroup.  This will only work when your view is not going to be placed next to another view in parent. This is usually the case for `ListView`, so may work for your case.

Comment: oh that make sense. The imageView(child) has margin set though. I should be able to get the margin in getView right?

Comment: I do not know for sure. If you inflated from XML, I would think they would be in the `LayoutParams`, but would have to try it out.